# Python exercise error

Tags: python-2.7

I am learning Python.
For code:

```
def main():
fileName = raw_input("file name ")
infile = open(fileName, "r")
sm = 0.0
ct = 0
line = infile.readline()
while line != "":
    sm = sm + eval(line)
    ct = ct + 1
    line = infile.readline()
print "\nAverage is  ", sm/ct

main()
```

it results the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sorin/avg6.py", line 13, in <module>
main()
File "/home/sorin/avg6.py", line 8, in main
sm = sm + eval(line)
File "<string>", line 1

^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I don't understand way. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `eval` function expects the string you pass it to be a valid Python expression, but it got an empty string (or, given the `while` loop's condition, perhaps a string with only whitespace). That doesn't have a value, so it raises an error.

You may want to look in the data file to see if there any blank lines (and remove them, if you can). Or you could modify the code to ignore invalid strings:

```
while line != "":
    try:
        sm = sm + eval(line)
        ct = ct + 1
    except SyntaxError:
        pass

    line = infile.readline()
```

You might also want to catch other kinds of errors, if you go that route.

Another option is to explicitly check for specific invalid strings that might come up (like just a bare newline):

```
while line != "":
    if line != "\n": # or maybe us "if line.strip()", to reject whitespace lines
        sm = sm + eval(line)
        ct = ct + 1

    line = infile.readline()
```

One final suggestion is to use a `for` loop on the file object rather than a `while` loop with calls to `readline`. This won't prevent the kinds of error you're getting, but it generally results in nicer looking code, which might be easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

What does your input file look like? If your input file has a blank line, it would explain your error.

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment, rather than an answer.